How to enable ctrl-q for blockwise visual selection on MacVim?
I have it working for Windows and WSL but not for MacVim.
How can I enable it in MacVim?

Could you tell us: The version of MacVim you are using and the keyboard layout you use (Qwerty-us, Azerty-be, ...)?

The Ctrl ^q turns block-wise visual selection on MacVim like Ctrl ^v does.
Remark: tested on MacVim 9.1.727 and Vim 9.0 included patches: 1-2136 on macOS Snonoma 14.6.1
